# How to create a cardView programatically?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-inflate

So I have this list of city objects (which contain an image, the name of the city, and a integer value). And for each of these city objects I want to programatically create a new cardView and insert it into a fragment. Currently, nothing shows up...

Here is my fragment xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragCards_LL">
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Here is the code for my fragment activity.

```
public class FragmentCards extends Fragment
{
    private ArrayList<CityFolders> cityFolders = new ArrayList<>();
    private OnCardsFragmentListener mListener;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private View view;

    public FragmentCards() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_cards, container, false);
        setUpLinearLayout();
        setUpCityFolders();
        //TextView myText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragCards_numberOfCardsTextContent);
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), myText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_cards, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnCardsFragmentListener)
        {
            mListener = (OnCardsFragmentListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnCheeseCategoriesFragmentListener");
        }
    }
    private void setUpLinearLayout()
    {
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fragCards_LL);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new NestedScrollView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }
    private void setUpCityFolders()
    {
        if(!Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().cityFoldersArrayList.isEmpty())
        {
            cityFolders = Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().cityFoldersArrayList;
            for(CityFolders cityFolder : cityFolders)
            {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                lp.setMargins(64,64,64,64);
                lp.height = 200;//180dp = 720pixels
                lp.width = 1408;//330dp = 1320 pixels.
                CardView cityCardView = new CardView(getActivity());// ERROR
                cityCardView.setBackgroundColor(000000);
                cityCardView.setLayoutParams(lp);
                linearLayout.addView(cityCardView, 0);
            }

        }
    }
    public interface OnCardsFragmentListener
    {
        void disableCollapse();
    }

}
```

So, don't know what I am doing wrong here... hope someone can help, maybe point out what im doing wrong?

Also, in my cardView, going horizontally, I want to have an imageview, then a textview, followed by another textview. How would I inflate those parts of the cardView and fill them with an image, and 2 texts from my cityFolder object? Hope you guys can help me with an answer!

Cheers

EDIT:

So i implemented a recycler view and..nothing shows up on the screen... This recycler view just holds simple views with each view having an imageview and a textview, and nothing shows up..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp"
            android:id="@+id/fragCards_LL">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fragCards_RecyclerView">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my xml code for the view for each item in the recycler view

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fullstar"
            android:id="@+id/fragCardsCity_imageview"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Star City"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/fragCardsCity_textView"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

And finally, here is my java code.

```
public class FragmentCards extends Fragment
{
    private ArrayList<CityFolders> cityFolders = new ArrayList<>();
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private View rootView;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private CityViewAdapter cityAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cards, container, false);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragCards_LL);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragCards_RecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        cityAdapter = new CityViewAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        return rootView;
    }
    public static ArrayList<myData> getData()
    {
        ArrayList<myData> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] icons = {R.drawable.fullstar,R.drawable.fullstar,R.drawable.fullstar,R.drawable.fullstar};
        String[] titles = {"San Francisco","Seattle","Tokyo","Osaka"};
        for(int i = 0; i < titles.length && i < icons.length; i++)
        {
            myData current = new myData();
            current.iconId = icons[i];
            current.cityName =  titles[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
    private static class myData
    {
        private int iconId;
        private String cityName;
    }
    private class CityViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CityViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>
    {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ArrayList<myData> infoList = new ArrayList<>();

        public CityViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<myData> data)
        {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.infoList = data;
        }
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cards_cityview,parent,false);
            MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);//special way to avoid "findViewById everytime you make a view
            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            myData current = infoList.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(current.cityName);
            holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 0;
        }
        class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            TextView title;
            ImageView icon;
            public MyViewHolder(View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);
                title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fragCardsCity_textView);
                icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fragCardsCity_imageview);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can create a custom view (https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) that has a CardView as layout and the items you asked inside. And them you can create your custom view besides the CardView and add it to your layout.

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.androhub.com/android-creating-layouts-programatically/).

Comment: So i realized that the code in the for loop to create the cardView works IF i put it onCreateView. So, that means, i can create only 1 cardView. I am wondering why I cannot create cardViews outside of onCreateView?

Comment: I implemented a recyclerview, and nothing shows up...so the edits above.